# Using typescript unions in methods throwing errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am relatively new to typescript and have what I believe to be a weird error.

I have multiple objects that use send data to the server, and then return fresh data of the same object back from the server.
The different objects use the same method to send the data, so I have used a `union` to specify that the method can take either of the two types, but I am getting an error.

I have made a [simple version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAxAlhANgCYBcUAzsAE44B2A5gNxqbZ5GkXX1MC+KKoSFABCCZMwBGuAiXJVajSVLayaAVwC2EiJRR8B4aAGVgawhBrAxcAD4imKAMYB7GhSjAI7xKnSsZpADkACpewIEANMwY-uxQIWGwdBi0gXr8Lm5WAGZqNI5wiAAUGKQwAJRlCAB84uiUEKaUNJi8Tq7uufmixRKkwpUiNXVQDU0tEm3tWVBdjmJFFGYWwKQmy5aD6+aWw76jjWrNchvAU4LQWHnzxUs7q1DbK+XDT5YO0+4uGmCuKwtzUhXfIveC1fZjI4tOZTb6-GgrIpzcoOOF-SxI64VVEdKwNMhqfBWRBzIqeCgojIdZz4CAAOnwzjoRXxhOA5RQQA) of the code to replicate the issue, which I can do.

```
type A = {
  aField: string;
  aaField: string;
}

type B = {
  bField: string;
  bbField: number
}

type Student = A | B;

type Func = (student: Student) => Student;

const test = {
  aField: 'Test',
  aaField: 'Test Again'
}

const funcA = (a: A): A => {
  return a;
}
const funcB = (b: B): B => {
  return b;
}

const func = (student: Student): Student => {
  return student;
}

const component = (func: Func) => {
  return func;
}

component(func);

component(funcA);
```

The error I am getting is as follows

> Argument of type '(a: A) => A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Func'.
> Types of parameters 'a' and 'student' are incompatible.
> Type 'Student' is not assignable to type 'A'.
> Type 'B' is missing the following properties from type 'A': aField, aaField

Is there a way I can get around this without having to cast each of the functions type?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXOZ9W) fit your need? If so I can write a more detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks @ghybs, this seems to be pretty similar to the other answers, which did indeed help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union type is more constraining than you may think, when used to type a *callback* parameter (like the `func` parameter of your `component` function).

When we have:

```
type Student = A | B;
type Func = (student: Student) => Student;
```

...we are saying that `Func` *must* accept an argument of type `Student`, which can be (at the *caller will*) either `A` or `B`.

That is what your `func` function does, but *not* `funcA` or `funcB`, which can already be seen if we try to type them as `Func`:

```
// Error: Type '(a: A) => A' is not assignable to type 'Func'.
const funcA: Func = (a: A): A => {
  //  ~~~~~
  return a;
}

// Error: Type '(b: B) => B' is not assignable to type 'Func'.
const funcB: Func = (b: B): B => {
  //  ~~~~~
  return b;
}

// Okay
const func: Func = (student: Student): Student => {
  return student;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAxAlhANgCYBcUAzsAE44B2A5gNxqbZ5GkXX1MC+KKoSFABCCZMwBGuAiXJVajSVLayaAVwC2EiJRR8B4aAGVgawhBrAxcAD4imKAMYB7GhSjAI7xKnSsZpADkACpewIEANMwY-uxQIWGwdBi0gXr8APQZUACilJTOlKTBhvEAFBikMACUCAB8sIFQOGRQNM5WGGRkOHQ0GBL40MDOHqWBWGo0joEAdE6u7gBmU44wpJPTYhVV1VX14uiUEKaUNJi8mdl5BUVQJUKBZRKkwrXwDcJNLW0dmN29fqDYajQTQCarOYLNxWFbTYQbVbbF4iPYiA6+KDHU7nCSXFBZKAAeQA1hgQNDlqtEVtEGUKGYLMBSCZGZY0azzJYMcxsWoznI2cB8WCoJtHNsGVzmVBOUz3g05ZYHJSrC4NGBXEztnDHDTHArDliTvzzrr8erNTQmWVddUHJatZZbasag7FlZjmQ1PgrIhdWVPBR7fwXG5nENZvhnHQyl6fcBqiggA)

`funcA` and `funcB` accept `A` and `B` respectively, but not a union `A | B` (`funcA` does not accept `B`, and reversely), hence they do not match `Func`.

---

> I have multiple objects that use send data to the server, and then return fresh data of the same object back from the server.

From your description, you rather need a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, that also gives the same type to the callback return:

```
const component2b = <T extends A | B>(func: (student: T) => T) => {
  return func;
}

component2b(funcA); // Okay
component2b(funcB); // Okay
```

With this `T extends A | B` generic type, we say that the `func` callback must accept an argument of a type `T` that is *assignable* to `A | B`, so `A` or `B` is fine (and not necessarily both simultaneously).

Furthermore, we also specify that `T` is the return type, so if the passed callback takes in `A`, it returns `A` type as well (and same for `B`), matching your description.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAxAlhANgCYBcUAzsAE44B2A5gNxqbZ5GkXX1MC+KKoSFABCCZMwBGuAiXJVajSVLayaAVwC2EiJRR8B4aAGVgawhBrAxcAD4imKAMYB7GhSjAI7xKnSsZpADkACpewIEANMwY-uxQIWGwdBi0gXr8Lm5WAGZqNI5wiAAUGKQwAJRlCAB84uiUEKaUNJi8Tq7uufmixRKkwpUiNXVQDU0tEm3tWVBdjmJFFGYWwKQmy5aD6+aWw76jjWrNchvAU4LQWHnzxUs7q1DbK+XDT5YO0+4uGmCuKwtzUhXfIveC1fZjI4tOZTb6-GgrIpzcoOOF-SxI64VVEdKwNMhqfBWRBzIqeCgojIdZz4CAAOnwzjoRXxhOA5X4AHpuTzebyqTM0QjLAAmCRiAA8wSgEAAHp4aIQyLAoHZhNVMflSItTPdSMFQbUDXtmJDjjD0u0fujgGLNQUUVBuVAAPIAawwICt8JWdrmAwYTs5ro9Xu9Nr910dzvdnpQQA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to distribute the `Student` union over matching function signatures:

```
type Func<S = Student> = S extends Student ? (student: S) => S : never;

component(func); // OK
component(funcA); // OK
component(funcB); // OK
```

---

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=72&pln=30&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAxAlhANgCYBcUAzsAE44B2A5gNxqbZ5GkXX1MC+KKoSFABCCZMwBGuAiXJVajSVLayaAVwC2EiJRR8B4aAGVgawhBrAxcAD4imKAMYB7GhSjAI7xKnSsZpADkACpewIEANMwY-uxQIWGwdBi0gXr8Lm5WAGZqNI5wiAAUGKQwAJRlCAB84uiUEKaUNJi8Ga7uufmixRKkwpUiNXVQDU0tEm1OHTl5jmIAPEZQEAAenjSEZFAmZhbA1UUUe5akRoPL8LW+o41qzXInwFOC0FhzS2K75pa1iMtrDZbHamH5WAD8UCOoP2Z3Kw2WpBoEAAbjoHJl3C4NGBXPsxEUuo5SO98vCriMxvcWkSptjccjLIS5uUmPS8UyiRU2c4cRzgMzuqz2llbmQ1PgrIgiUVPBRhdM3M58BAAHT4Zx0IoNcWS8ooIA) with a complete snippet.